# Username in domain after slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, web

What is the best way to rewrite the url from

```
https://www.example.com/user/?user=MaxMustermann
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/MaxMustermann
```

I have tried that in the .htaccess-File with a RewriteRule, but if I open the URL exmaple.com/login.php, I get the Message "User not found", whats correctly. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show us what you got! You'd need to make sure you're not rewriting existing files, like `-f` would skip the rewrite if a "real" file with that name exists: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yes, /user is a real directory. Content of my htaccess:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user/index.php?user=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new site root `.htaccess` and have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(user)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/?user=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: i have create the .htaccess in the user directory, but it didn't worked. I don't know how RewriteRules are working, but i think the .htaccess in the root-directory is the problem.

Comment: i tried to open: `example.com/username` here i get the user page. But when i open `example.com/login.php` i get the error "user not found".

Comment: now i have the problem, that i can't open `example.com/login.php`

Comment: `example.com/login.php` has nothing to do with this rule as this rule only impacts a URI that starts with `/user/`. Investigate in your code why that is happening.

Comment: I have now removed my RewriteRules in the root htaccess. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I have index.php like this in folder called user:

```
  <?php 
       $userid = 10; 
         if($userUrl = "gadiradufasha") {
    include("../profile.php");
      }
    ?>
```

and then I have: profile.php in backward folder w/c I call once!

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include ('query.php');
$object = new Query;

if(!isset($_SESSION['UserId'])) {
  header("Location:../../");
}

$user= $userUrl;

if($user!=$_SESSION['User']) {
//$prostmt = $object->getUserDetails($userUrl);
$prostmt = $object->getUserDetailsByUsername($userUrl);
$profrow = $prostmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```